# EJB @scheduler method invocation failed

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, scheduler

I am trying to work with @scheduler however it is failed to call my EJB2 object. Is it because @scheduler is in EJB 3.1 and I am trying to call EJB2 therefor it do not support it?? or is there something missing:

```
@Singleton
public class BatchUserPermissionUpdater {

Date now;   
@Inject
private IUserCompanyPermission permission;
@EJB
private CompanyBusiness companyBusiness;

@Schedule(minute="*/1",hour="*", persistent=false)
public void execute() {     
     now = new Date();
     Logger.instance().logInfo(this,"Executing scheduler. Time is :" + now);

     List<UserCompanyPermission> userList= permission.findAllUserCompanyPermission();

     if(userList!=null && !userList.isEmpty()){
           updateAccess(userList);
                        }
                    }

public void updateAccess(List<UserCompanyPermission> userList)  {

     for ( UserCompanyPermission list : userList) {
       Company company =  companyBusiness.getCompanyBySID(list.getCompanyId());

               }
            }

        }
```

When It reach to line below it throw Exception:

> Company company = 
>   companyBusiness.getCompanyBySID(list.getCompanyId());

```
@Stateless
public class CompanyFacadeImpl extends EntityServiceImpl<CompanyEntity, Long> implements CompanyBusiness {

@EJB
CompanyHome companyHome;

@Override
public Company getCompanyBySID(long id) throws RemoteException, FinderException {
    return companyHome.findByPrimaryKey(new SnapshotPK(id));
    }

}
```

CompanyHome :

```
public interface CompanyHome extends EJBHome {
 public Company findByPrimaryKey(SnapshotPK pk) throws RemoteException, FinderException;
}
```

Following exception is thrown:

```
    [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (EJB default - 1) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component Company for method public abstract com.iumnordic.snapshot.remote.Company com.iumnordic.snapshot.home.CompanyHome.findByPrimaryKey(com.iumnordic.snapshot.util.SnapshotPK) throws java.rmi.RemoteException,javax.ejb.FinderException: javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: JBAS014502: Invocation on method: public abstract com.iumnordic.snapshot.remote.Company com.iumnordic.snapshot.home.CompanyHome.findByPrimaryKey(com.iumnordic.snapshot.util.SnapshotPK) throws java.rmi.RemoteException,javax.ejb.FinderException of bean: Company is not allowed
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy146.findByPrimaryKey(Unknown Source)
    at com.iumnordic.snapshotx.ejb.stateless.DefaultCompanyFacadeImpl.getCompanyBySID(DefaultCompanyFacadeImpl.java:222) [snapshot-ejb3-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
 com.iumnordic.snapshotx.ejb.business.CompanyBusiness$$$view75.getCompanyBySID(Unknown Source) [snapshot-ejb3-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at com.iumnordic.timertask.BatchUserPermissionUpdater.updateAccess(BatchUserPermissionUpdater.java:79)
    at com.iumnordic.timertask.BatchUserPermissionUpdater.execute(BatchUserPermissionUpdater.java:58)
```

Code above is working fine outside the scheduler throughout in application so I am sure it has something to do with @Scheduler what exactly it is not sure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just a hint, try to use a '@Stateless' instead of '@Singleton'

Comment: I did try both before I posted but no luck.

Comment: This is interesting from the stack trace seems like a wiring problem. Which AS you use?

Comment: I am using JBoss 6.1